# C# Protobuf - Problem Generating the C# Code From .proton File

Tags: c#, grpc, protobuf-net

I have the following problem: I am trying to call the following protobuf interface using Visual Studio 2022 and .NET Core 3.1 LTS:

```
 syntax = "proto3";
 package tak;

message GameParameter {
  uint32 board_length = 1;
}

enum Direction {
  NORTH = 0;
  EAST = 1;
  SOUTH = 2;
  WEST = 3;
}

enum PieceType {
  FLAT_STONE = 0;
  STANDING_STONE = 1;
  CAPSTONE = 2;
}

message PlaceAction {
  PieceType piece = 1;
}

message MoveAction {
  Direction direction = 1;
  repeated uint32 drops = 2;
}

message GameTurn {
  uint32 x = 1;
  uint32 y = 2;
  oneof Action {
    PlaceAction place = 3;
    MoveAction move = 4;
  }
}

message Piece {
  PieceType type = 1;
  bool second_player_owned = 2;
}

message Pile {
  repeated Piece pieces = 1;
}

message GameState {
  uint32 board_length = 1;
  repeated uint32 remaining_stones = 2;
  repeated uint32 remaining_capstones = 3;
  repeated Pile board = 4;
}
```

When I am building the project, the sample Greeter Service gets generated correctly and works. However, while Tak.cs is generated, TakGrpc.cs is an empty file. Since I have almost no experience with protobuf, I am not sure if that is supposed to happen, but I assume not. Anyways, I am now stuck, as I cannot follow those tutorials that assume a Base class from which the service could inherit from.

Just to clarify, I did set Build Action to "Protobuf compiler" and I also set gRPC to "Client and Server". I also tried "Server only" and "Client only"

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

From the above link, I think you probably have not done the below to-do's.

```
Add a package reference to Grpc.Tools package.

Add .proto files to the <Protobuf> item group.
```

..

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="Protos\greet.proto" />
</ItemGroup>
```